# Absolute Beginner React Button Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, axios, create-react-app

I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and attempting to modify the App.js file to have a button that has an onclick method that makes an axios HTTP request. I have been trying this for a couple weeks and the error I've gotten the most has been unexpected token in my handleClick(e). [I tried this](https://codepad.co/snippet/l0TM5fRk) and I don't understand why it won't compile:

```
// Example React.js Component

var ButtonComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            numClicks: 0
        }
    }
   click: function() {
        this.setState(numClicks: this.state.numClicks + 1);
    },
    render: function() {
       return  (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>  
            {this.state.numClicks}
        </div>
       );
   } 
});
```

If anyone could provide some help I would really appreciate it. I just want to be able to render components that can make requests to my express app.

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors, one comma missing before `click`, missing braces in `setState` -> `setState({ numClicks: this.state.numClicks + 1 })` and maybe you're not importing `React`

Comment: I'm a complete beginner so I don't know what's wrong with the syntax. Is there anywhere you can link me to that has an example of something similar to what I would like to do? Thanks!!

Comment: first look, you are using a deprecated syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a deprecated syntax, use instead React with ES6.

And about your problem you have multiple syntax errors:

- One comma missing after `getInitialState` closing brace.
- Missing braces in `this.setState()`
- Probably you're not importing react

Here's the code with the corrections:

```
var ButtonComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      numClicks: 0
    }
  },
  click: function() {
    this.setState({ numClicks: this.state.numClicks + 1 });
  },
  render: function() {
    return  (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>
        {this.state.numClicks}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I would recommend you read the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html)/[guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html) and switch to ES6.

Here's the code also with ES6:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ButtonComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      numClicks: 0
    }
  }

  click() {
    this.setState({ numClicks: this.state.numClicks + 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return  (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>
        {this.state.numClicks}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

`React.createClass` is deprecated. Use ES6 classes. In `src/App.js` from the react  app you created using `create-react-app` try the following:

```
class App extends Component {
  onClick() {
    // axios request
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.onClick() }>Axios Request</button>
    );
  }
}
```

The [official  tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) is a good place to learn React basics.

Once you get started and are familiar with the syntax I highly recommend ready [Sebmarbage's react-basics](https://github.com/reactjs/react-basic) explaining theoretical concepts.

Comment: Thank you so much!